# Create dropdown of timezones having UTC/GMT

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a requirement where I need to show dropDown list containing  timezones in `UTC/GMT` format

Below I have tried to achieve the same using `moment.js` and `momenttimezone.js`

```js
var select = document.getElementById('timezones');
moment.tz.names().forEach(function(timezone){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent =  moment.tz(timezone).format('Z z') +timezone ;
  select.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<select id="timezones">

</select>
<br><br><br><br>

<select>
    <option timeZoneId="1" gmtAdjustment="GMT-12:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-12">(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
    <option timeZoneId="2" gmtAdjustment="GMT-11:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-11">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
    <option timeZoneId="3" gmtAdjustment="GMT-10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-10">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
    <option timeZoneId="4" gmtAdjustment="GMT-09:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-9">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
    <option timeZoneId="5" gmtAdjustment="GMT-08:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-8">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="6" gmtAdjustment="GMT-08:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-8">(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California</option>
    <option timeZoneId="7" gmtAdjustment="GMT-07:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-7">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>
    <option timeZoneId="8" gmtAdjustment="GMT-07:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-7">(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan</option>
    <option timeZoneId="9" gmtAdjustment="GMT-07:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-7">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="10" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-6">(GMT-06:00) Central America</option>
    <option timeZoneId="11" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-6">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="12" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-6">(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey</option>
    <option timeZoneId="13" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-6">(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan</option>
    <option timeZoneId="14" gmtAdjustment="GMT-05:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-5">(GMT-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco</option>
    <option timeZoneId="15" gmtAdjustment="GMT-05:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-5">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="16" gmtAdjustment="GMT-05:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-5">(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="17" gmtAdjustment="GMT-04:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="18" gmtAdjustment="GMT-04:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Caracas, La Paz</option>
    <option timeZoneId="19" gmtAdjustment="GMT-04:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Manaus</option>
    <option timeZoneId="20" gmtAdjustment="GMT-04:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Santiago</option>
    <option timeZoneId="21" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:30" useDaylightTime="1" value="-3.5">(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland</option>
    <option timeZoneId="22" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Brasilia</option>
    <option timeZoneId="23" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires, Georgetown</option>
    <option timeZoneId="24" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Greenland</option>
    <option timeZoneId="25" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Montevideo</option>
    <option timeZoneId="26" gmtAdjustment="GMT-02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-2">(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic</option>
    <option timeZoneId="27" gmtAdjustment="GMT-01:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-1">(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is.</option>
    <option timeZoneId="28" gmtAdjustment="GMT-01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-1">(GMT-01:00) Azores</option>
    <option timeZoneId="29" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="0">(GMT+00:00) Casablanca, Monrovia, Reykjavik</option>
    <option timeZoneId="30" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="0">(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option>
    <option timeZoneId="31" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</option>
    <option timeZoneId="32" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
    <option timeZoneId="33" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
    <option timeZoneId="34" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb</option>
    <option timeZoneId="35" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa</option>
    <option timeZoneId="36" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Amman</option>
    <option timeZoneId="37" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul</option>
    <option timeZoneId="38" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Beirut</option>
    <option timeZoneId="39" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Cairo</option>
    <option timeZoneId="40" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Harare, Pretoria</option>
    <option timeZoneId="41" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius</option>
    <option timeZoneId="42" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem</option>
    <option timeZoneId="43" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Minsk</option>
    <option timeZoneId="44" gmtAdjustment="GMT+02:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="2">(GMT+02:00) Windhoek</option>
    <option timeZoneId="45" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="3">(GMT+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh, Baghdad</option>
    <option timeZoneId="46" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="3">(GMT+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd</option>
    <option timeZoneId="47" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="3">(GMT+03:00) Nairobi</option>
    <option timeZoneId="48" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="3">(GMT+03:00) Tbilisi</option>
    <option timeZoneId="49" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:30" useDaylightTime="1" value="3.5">(GMT+03:30) Tehran</option>
    <option timeZoneId="50" gmtAdjustment="GMT+04:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="4">(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat</option>
    <option timeZoneId="51" gmtAdjustment="GMT+04:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="4">(GMT+04:00) Baku</option>
    <option timeZoneId="52" gmtAdjustment="GMT+04:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="4">(GMT+04:00) Yerevan</option>
    <option timeZoneId="53" gmtAdjustment="GMT+04:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="4.5">(GMT+04:30) Kabul</option>
    <option timeZoneId="54" gmtAdjustment="GMT+05:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="5">(GMT+05:00) Yekaterinburg</option>
    <option timeZoneId="55" gmtAdjustment="GMT+05:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="5">(GMT+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent</option>
    <option timeZoneId="56" gmtAdjustment="GMT+05:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="5.5">(GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenapura</option>
    <option timeZoneId="57" gmtAdjustment="GMT+05:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="5.5">(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</option>
    <option timeZoneId="58" gmtAdjustment="GMT+05:45" useDaylightTime="0" value="5.75">(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu</option>
    <option timeZoneId="59" gmtAdjustment="GMT+06:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="6">(GMT+06:00) Almaty, Novosibirsk</option>
    <option timeZoneId="60" gmtAdjustment="GMT+06:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="6">(GMT+06:00) Astana, Dhaka</option>
    <option timeZoneId="61" gmtAdjustment="GMT+06:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="6.5">(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)</option>
    <option timeZoneId="62" gmtAdjustment="GMT+07:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="7">(GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
    <option timeZoneId="63" gmtAdjustment="GMT+07:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="7">(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk</option>
    <option timeZoneId="64" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi</option>
    <option timeZoneId="65" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore</option>
    <option timeZoneId="66" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar</option>
    <option timeZoneId="67" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Perth</option>
    <option timeZoneId="68" gmtAdjustment="GMT+08:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="8">(GMT+08:00) Taipei</option>
    <option timeZoneId="69" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo</option>
    <option timeZoneId="70" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Seoul</option>
    <option timeZoneId="71" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="9">(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk</option>
    <option timeZoneId="72" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="9.5">(GMT+09:30) Adelaide</option>
    <option timeZoneId="73" gmtAdjustment="GMT+09:30" useDaylightTime="0" value="9.5">(GMT+09:30) Darwin</option>
    <option timeZoneId="74" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Brisbane</option>
    <option timeZoneId="75" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney</option>
    <option timeZoneId="76" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Hobart</option>
    <option timeZoneId="77" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby</option>
    <option timeZoneId="78" gmtAdjustment="GMT+10:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="10">(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok</option>
    <option timeZoneId="79" gmtAdjustment="GMT+11:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="11">(GMT+11:00) Magadan, Solomon Is., New Caledonia</option>
    <option timeZoneId="80" gmtAdjustment="GMT+12:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="12">(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington</option>
    <option timeZoneId="81" gmtAdjustment="GMT+12:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="12">(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.</option>
    <option timeZoneId="82" gmtAdjustment="GMT+13:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="13">(GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in the first DropDown I'm getting the timezones but not in the format I need to. The second dropdown is the format I want to achieve.

Comment: This still isn't any clearer than the last time you posted this. Tell us what exactly is "required" and what problem you have with your code as is.

Comment: @deceze I updated the question in order to clarify what he needs.